# Apply style from library to wpf

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, resourcedictionary

I have found plenty of examples but none of them worked for me.
How do I include the style?

this is my project structure:
[image]

and this is my xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestLibrary.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestLibrary"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Kryptomine_Styling;TabControlStyles.xaml/"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="test1"></TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="test2"></TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="test3"></TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Kryptomine_Styling;component/TabControlStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

you need to add `component/` (~base dir) and in the end there may not be a `/`